# How to change "string" to "integer" in each feature properties of feature collection in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-class, feature-collection

Is there any way other than using `map` function to convert string data type of a property of a feature in feature collection?
Could we change type of data in a property of all features in a feature collection?

```
var Shape = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, {'Land Cover': '0'})]); 
  print('Feature Collection with string property',Shape)

var mapping = ee.Dictionary({
  '0': 0,
  '1': 1,
  '2': 2
});


var mapped = Shape
  .select(['Land Cover'])
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('class', mapping.get(feature.get('Land Cover')));
  });

print('Feature Collection with string and integer property',mapped);
```

[sample code in GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5cb1f1e457da37239436b5e720512eb5)

Comment: No.  Map() is how you do something to every feature.  You could just use ee.Number.parse to do the conversion instead of a dictionary though.  (no big cost difference)